# How can I save any file with a space within its filename with vi?

Tags: vim

I mostly use vim from the terminal by **vi** command.

I want to create and save a file named something like **getting started.txt** (there is space between two words). I tried two methods:

### Method #1

```
:sav getting started.txt
```

but I got an error : *`E172: Only one file name allowed`*

### Method #2

```
:sav "getting started.txt"
```

This time I got : *`E471: Argument required`*

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Maybe try     :sav "getting%20started.txt"

Comment: @azulflame that won't work, I think you'll probably end up with a file named: `getting20started.txt`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escape the space character:

```
:sav getting\ started.txt
```

Comment: See also `:help fnameescape`.

Comment: The function is almost useless. Why can't I do something easy as :sav "<c-r>%.new_extension" ? Every editor/terminal in this word you can escape white spasce with doubled or single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Commenter @ib mentions `fnameescape`, here's how you can use it:

1. Enter `:save` and a space.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>=</kbd> to enter expression mode.
3. Enter `fnameescape("Your spacey, special character'y file name")`. <kbd>Tab</kbd> expansion works, so you can probably do `fn`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`e`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the escaped file name into your command line.

Poster [iler.ml suggests](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-auto-escape-space-in-filename-when-write-td1149064.html) a function to do this easily (I've modified his code slightly). Put this in your *.vimrc*:

```
" :W and :Save will escape a file name and write it
command! -bang -nargs=* W :call W(<q-bang>, <q-args>) 
command! -bang -nargs=* Save :call Save(<q-bang>, <q-args>) 

function! W(bang, filename) 
    :exe "w".a:bang." ". fnameescape(a:filename) 
endfu 

function! Save(bang, filename) 
    :exe "save".a:bang." ". fnameescape(a:filename) 
endfu
```