# GVim set shellslash create new file for path with space on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I am using GVim with the `set shellslash` option. Whenever I try to open a path with a space in it, like `C:/Users/My Name/MyFile.java` I get a new file (within a new directory), because Vim consider that the file would be `C:/Users/My/ Name/MyFile.java`, which is wrong. Anyway around this keeping the `shellslash` option on?

### Update

Another example: in NERDTree, if I go to a file an press `o` and the file contain spaces in the path, it is not opened (using the `shellslash` option), but I get a new file.

Comment: don't have windows to test, however can you try quote the path with spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save any file with a space within its filename with vi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058017/how-can-i-save-any-file-with-a-space-within-its-filename-with-vi)

Comment: I believe this question is different from the one you mention. I updated it to make it clearer.

Comment: This, then, looks like a bug in NERDTree. Contact the maintainer. I believe there is a GitHub repository with issue tracker.